# Clearing the cart when entering and leaving a certain page in wordpress and woocommerce

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

So I have a page with id 51 (in here there are some products I can add in the cart), I want to clear the products from the shopping cart when I enter this page, but then after I add some products in the cart, while I am on this page, I also want to clear the cart when I leave the page.
To put it more simply I want to clear the shopping cart every time I enter or leave the page with ID 51.

I have tried many approaches but this one is the most simple, the cart is cleared when I enter the page, but is not cleared when I leave the page, I used a session cookie to check if I am on the page with id 51, so if I am on this page, when I leave it the cart should be cleared.

```
// Clear the cart when entering and leaving page with ID 51
function clear_cart_on_page_51() {
    // Get the current page ID
    $current_page_id = get_queried_object_id();

    // Check if the current page has an ID of 51
    if ($current_page_id == 51) {
        // Set a session variable to indicate that you're on page 51
        $_SESSION['on_page_51'] = true;

        // Clear the WooCommerce cart when entering the page
        WC()->cart->empty_cart();
    } elseif (isset($_SESSION['on_page_51']) && $_SESSION['on_page_51'] == true) {
        // Clear the WooCommerce cart when leaving the page with ID 51
        WC()->cart->empty_cart();

        // Unset the session variable to indicate that you've left the page
        unset($_SESSION['on_page_51']);
    }
}

// Hook the function to run during template redirection
add_action('template_redirect', 'clear_cart_on_page_51');

// Add JavaScript to send a console notification when the session variable is set
function add_console_notification_script() {
    // Check if the session variable 'on_page_51' is set
    if (isset($_SESSION['on_page_51']) && $_SESSION['on_page_51'] == true) {
        echo '<script>';
        echo 'console.log("You are on or have previously visited page 51.");';
        echo '</script>';
    }
}

// Hook the JavaScript function to wp_footer
add_action('wp_footer', 'add_console_notification_script');
```

`

I also used the last function to see if the session cookie is set, and that works, but when I leave the page the cart is not cleared. All the code is in the functions.php file.
I saw the other two questions similar to mine from stackoverflow, but neither of them had the functionality to clear the cart when entering the page and when exiting the page.
Could you please help me?

Comment: I would prefer using js beforeunload which will tell if user leaves the website.

Answer (score 0):

Here is in my opinion better approach

Create new or use exsisting js file

```
wp_enqueue_script('your-script-handle', 'path-to-your-script.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
```

We need to define our ajax url

```
wp_localize_script('your-script-handle', 'ajax_object', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
```

In the new file add the following

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
    // Perform an AJAX request to clear the cart
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: ajax_object.ajaxurl, // WordPress AJAX URL
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            action: 'clear_cart' // Action hook to trigger the server-side function
        },
        success: function (response) {
            // Handle the server's response if needed
        }
    });
});
```

And this is our function

```
//Create function that we will execute on ajax
add_action('wp_ajax_clear_cart', 'clear_cart');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_clear_cart', 'clear_cart');

function clear_cart() {
    $specific_page_ids = array(1, 2, 3); // add pages from which we want to clear
    $current_page_id = get_queried_object_id();
    // add conditions here 
    if (in_array($current_page_id, $specific_page_ids)) {
        WC()->cart->empty_cart();
        wp_send_json_success(); // You can send a success response back to the client if needed
    }
}
```